# Difference between x86_64 and i386 for installing Fedora18

Tags: linux

What is the difference? I have intel pentium dual core P6200. Under what category my system fall into? I want to download fedora18. It shows me these options(x86_64 and i386). Which one should I download? Are there any commands in Windows to know the same through command prompt ?
Also my processor is 64 bit compatible .

Answer (score 2):

For a 64bit capable processor, you want the x86_64 version. i386 is 32bit only, meaning that it will function only as a 32 bit OS. x86_64 will function either way.